# How to use sed/awk to replace the original file and get the following desired output?

Tags: awk, sed

I'm writing a bash scrip that would translate one file to another, and am encountering an issue.

Whenever the program sees something like this(......not included):

> ......Mul(-a1+b2-c3...+f+e)......

change it to:

> ......M(-a1)*M(b2)*M(-c3)*...*M(f)*M(e)......

the number of the variables in Mul is unknown and there could be multiple occurrence of Mul in the file. There are also other places in the file where + or - appears. And Variables could be one or more characters.

I tried grouping in sed, with a group followed by a "*", but it doesn't seem to be working due to the need of replacing unknown amount of variables.

Comment: Why oh why do people insist in putting `...`s in their examples??? Please get rid of the `.`s and simply create a sample line of text that we can test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sed script that will do it:

```
:a
s/\(Mul(.[^)]*\)\([+-].\)/\1)*Mul(\2/
ta
s/Mul(+\{0,1\}/M(/g
```

The trick is to use the [test](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-59) to jump back to the beginning after making a substitution (e.g. "Mul(a+b+c)"=>"Mul(a)*Mul(+b+c)").

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/Mul\([^()]+\)/) {
    tgt = substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-5)
    gsub(/[-+][[:alnum:]]+/,"*M(&)",tgt)
    gsub(/\+/,"",tgt)
    sub(/^\*/,"",tgt)
    print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
......M(-a1)*M(b2)*M(-c3)*M(f)*M(e)......
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
......Mul(-a1+b2-c3+f+e)......
```